# How to display a circle within a td by adding a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and I would like to change a class on the `td` by clicking them. When I `addClass()` each cell changes but it seems override any class.

My desired result for each cell is like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this by adding a class to them?

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('outpatient');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.outpatient {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your class overrides TD state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this can create another element inside each `td`. The `td` will be used to display the square with the teal background. The inner element is necessary to show the circle with the yellow background. By default the circle can be hidden, and then displayed when the class is added to the parent `td`. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('outpatient');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

td div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: -1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td.outpatient div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>1</div></td>
    <td><div>2</div></td>
    <td><div>3</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>4</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>6</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>7</div></td>
    <td><div>8</div></td>
    <td><div>9</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `background-image` with radial-gradient to create the circle above the `background-color`

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('outpatient');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:aqua;
}
.outpatient {
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,yellow calc(100% - 3px),#000 calc(100% - 2px),transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```